# GitHub - Sign-In pop up on every authentication on windows

Tags: git, github

Every time I interact with my private work organisation on GitHub Enterprise via git (via https), I get a pop-up "Connect to GitHub" asking to sign in. I click on "Sign in with your browser", then my browser opens a page with a url like "http://127.0.0.1:51353/?code=62d57080f...&state=60791376d5da..." and finally the cli is authenticated.

[image]

It used to work without it by using the SSO token stored on my windows work machine - I think this is the work of the [Git Credential Manager](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git): If I check "Manage Windows Credentials" -> "Windows Credentials", I can see the entry "git:https://github.com":

```
Internet or network address: git:https://github.com
User name: FirstName-LastName_organisation
Password: *****
Persistence: Local computer
```

When I remove this credential and open "https://github.com/enterprises/my-org/sso" I get a page saying "Single sign-on to Your Organisation". I click continue and I am logged in. When I check the windows credential manager again, the credential I pasted above is there again.

Here is my git cli version and config:
version: `git version 2.42.0.windows.1`
config:

```
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain                                           
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f                                            
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f                                          
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process                                       
filter.lfs.required=true                                                        
http.sslbackend=openssl                                                         
http.sslcainfo=C:/dev/bin/git/mingw64/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt               
core.autocrlf=true                                                              
core.fscache=true                                                               
core.symlinks=false                                                             
pull.rebase=false                                                               
credential.helper=manager                                                       
credential.https://dev.azure.com.usehttppath=true                               
init.defaultbranch=master                                                       
user.name=FirstName-LastName_organisation                                               
user.email=FirstName.LastName@organisation.com                                    
http.sslverify=false                                                            
core.repositoryformatversion=0                                                  
core.filemode=false                                                             
core.bare=false                                                                 
core.logallrefupdates=true                                                      
core.symlinks=false                                                             
core.ignorecase=true
```

To me, what looks wrong, is the entry `credential.https`, though for my colleagues it looks the same (we are also using Azure Devops...)

Answer (score 1):

use ssh to auth for your cli git client

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

If you have a "clever" security org that blocks ssh egress on port 22, you can ssh to github.com over port 443

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port

Comment: dont ask me why but my organisation blocked connecting to github via ssh, it must be https...

Comment: It's likely they're blocking port 22, you can ssh over 443 to get around it. 


https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port